# UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator property is doesn't show on iPhone6s, But on like the XR and simulator it works fine

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, simulator

I use a custom cell, and then use it to give `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` `accessoryType`assignment, Of course I could just customize an arrow control instead of the accessoryType property, but I don't know why the 6s doesn't show, is it the system version or the phone model? I feel like I didn't do a lot of additional code manipulation to judge parameters like model system. I wonder if anyone has ever encountered this.

Comment: Do you have `dark mode` turned on on your 6s ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249010/how-do-i-make-uitableviewcellaccessorydisclosureindicator-visible-in-black-backg ?
Have you tried to debug the view hierarchy?

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov I tried debugging view hierarchy, there's ```accessoryView``` on 6s but there's no arrow on it. Dark mode is not on.

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a sample project, or provide some code from your project, or screenshots of an app with and without arrow. View Hierarchy? To avoid asking direct questions one-by-one. Well-asked question will gain more attention and likely to be answered.

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov get it !